# Dynamic Order by using Case in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get dynamic Order by based on the parameter in Oracle sql,Base on the condition any one of the Dynamic Order by to be binded ,What is wrong with my query please help to solve this.Parameter value will be passed dynamically for user.

```
SELECT actionstatus,
       id 
  FROM rdt_orderdetail
 WHERE id IN (45565,44033,45761,45543,45495,43472,42462,43477)

CASE WHEN ':user' = 'supplier THEN ORDER BY id 
  ELSE ORDER BY actionstatus
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT actionstatus,
       id 
 FROM rdt_orderdetail
 WHERE id IN (45565,44033,45761,45543,45495,43472,42462,43477)
 order by (CASE WHEN ':user' = 'supplier THEN id 
                                         ELSE actionstatus END)
```

[Example fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16441/2)

Comment: Short and Sweet Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use dynamic order ? Then you'll have to use dynamic SQL :-)

```
create or replace function GET_DETAILS(iField in varchar2) return sys_refcursor is
  aQuery varchar2(1000);
  aCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
  aQuery := 'select actionstatus,id from rdt_orderdetail
             where id in (45565,44033,45761,45543,45495,43472,42462,43477)
             order by ' || case iField when 'sup' then 'id' else 'actionstatus' end;
  open aCursor for aQuery;
  return aCursor;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `CASE` outside of a `SELECT` clause. 
Futhermore `'sup'` always equals `'sup'`, so it doesn't make sence anyway.

And about whole logic - you ordering the whole resultset, so it either by `id` or by `actionstatus`. You can not order couple of rows by `id`, and the next 3 by `actionstatus`

Comment: Thanks for reply.Pls check updated the Question then how to achive this.?

Comment: Like I said, you can not order couple of rows by id, and the next 3 by actionstatus